# How to set timers for console commands in symfony 2.x?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

In my app I've got one task that needs to be done every 48 hours on server side. I've created a console command in order to automatize my job. However I don't know how can I set timer to keep invoking that command. Can you point my a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see on a cron commands.

Cron will run your command every X (frequency) times.

TO create a cron, (on unix) use: crontab -e
For example

```
0 0 */2 * * bin/console app:command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will run every odd days, bin/console app:command

to help you generating a cron

https://crontab-generator.org/

Comment: You can see some some instructions how to add a cron job here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/